# Can't get value from ruby #<Money:2.5>

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, shopify

I am using shopify script editor but when i try to get value like cart.line_items.Money it doesn't return value but when i do the output using puts it gives me this

```
#<Money:'2.5'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a method to get the Money object's amount on the official [documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/checkout-settings/script-editor/shopify-scripts#money). However, it should have an implementation to return it's value. There are a few possibilities to find out what works for you:

1. It is likely that it implements methods like `to_s` or `to_f` or something alike. However, if it doesn't, you can go with option 2 (complementary).
2. Get the Money instance and take a look at the methods you can send to it:

`money_obj` being the Money object, you can run: `money_obj.class.instance_methods`.

That'll give you the list of methods you can call on `money_obj`. Further, you can look for certain keywords running `money_obj.class.instance_methods.grep('keyword')` and even see those methods only belonging to the Money class: `money_obj.class.instance_methods(false)`.

I'm aware this might not directly answer your question, but I though it can point you in the right direction.